# risk of developing type 2 diabetes by around a fifth -- "by around a fifth"?

Tags: comprehension

Source: [Never mind the food you eat... what you drink could be making you fat](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2385135/Never-mind-food--cups-tea-making-fat.html)

Example:

> A study earlier this year found that having just one can of sugary, fizzy drink a day can increase your risk of developing type 2 diabetes **by around a fifth**, for example.

I don't understand what **by around a fifth** means here.

Comment: *Around* means *about* (or *approximately*). *A fifth* means *one fifth* (or 20%). So "around a fifth" means "approximately 20%".

Comment: *by around a fifth* is a measure of the increase, not of the risk.

Comment: That's really bad way to describe the increase in risk since 10% -> 12% (no big deal), but 50% -> 60% (scary!).  It's dependent on the individual's susceptibility to type-2 diabetes.